# Why can't I access Fragment? (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment, which has two defined Fragments in a RelativeLayout in the XML layout, which are lying on top of each other. What I want to do is onCreateView to hide the first and later with a switchbutton to switch between both. This is whatmy OnCreateView looks like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_questions_slide_page, container, false);

FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.firstFragment));
ft.commit();
```

When I run the app, I get the following error. Any ideas?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1017)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:976)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
```

In case it makes a difference, the Fragment is initiated by a PagerAdapter which is set to a ViewPager.

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); delivers the same result

Comment: Are you calling hide() or show() with null values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getChildFragmentManager` for find fragments that you want to hide/show.

Also you should search for fragments in container where they are, not by fragments `id`

Answer (score 0):

The hint from @mohax was good. Here is the working code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_questions_slide_page, container, false);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.firstFragment))
    transaction.commit();
```

The Transaction is done by getFragmentManager and to identify the fragment you have to call getChildFragmentManager. Thanks!